# How to find general solution for this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm trying to find the general solution to this matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&3&0\\2&-4&4&6&4\\ -2&4&-1&-6&2\\1&-2&-3&3&-8\end{bmatrix}

Ax=$\begin{bmatrix}1&6&0&-7&\end{bmatrix}^T$

I think I'm supposed to get it in x=x*+z format, I'm still not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
But I ended up getting this matrix in row echelon form.
-2(r1)+(r2)

2(r1)+(r3)

-(r1)+(r4)
\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&3&0\\0&0&2&0&4\\ 0&0&1&0&2\\0&0&-4&0&-8\end{bmatrix}

And then

2(r2)+(r4)

-1/2(r2)+(r3)

\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&3&0\\0&0&2&0&4\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

then

1/2(r2)

\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&1&3&0\\0&0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

and lastly  -r2 + r2

\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&3&-2\\0&0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

after doing some algebra i ended up getting

x1 = 2(x2)-3(x4)-2(x5)

x3 = -2(x5)

and set x5 = x4 = x2 = 1

and got z =  $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-2&1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$

But I'm when i try to solve for Ax = $\begin{bmatrix}1&6&0&-7\end{bmatrix}^T$

The last two rows are full of zeros

so I can't have 0=-7

How would i solve this?

Comment: You can (insert the right hand side as an additional column and) perform the same row operations to arrive to the new right hand side

Comment: @Berci thanks , i think i got it now, is my z correct? I just realized i have 5 rows in it but my x* has 4

Comment: I think it(z) should be $[-2\  3 -1\  4]^T$ and definitely not 5 components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with the *augmented matrix*, and do the same operations on the rows of this matrix (including the supplementary column). Here is how it goes:

\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr|r@{}}
1&-2&1&3&0&1\\2&-4&4&6&4&6\\-2&4&-1&-6&2&0\\1&-2&-3&3&-8&-7
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr|r@{}}
1&-2&1&3&0&1\\0&0&2&0&4&4\\0&0&1&0&2&2\\0&0&-4&0&-8&-8
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\\
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr|r@{}}
1&-2&1&3&0&1\\0&0&1&0&2&2\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr|r@{}}
1&-2&0&3&-2&-1\\0&0&1&0&2&2\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

so the solutions are given by the equations
\begin{cases}
x_1=2x_2-3x_4-2x_5-1,\\
x_3=-2x_5+2.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  (As in the comments) begin with $\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr|r} 1&-2&1&3&0&1\\2&-4&4&6&4&6\\-2&4&-1&-6&2&0\\1&-2&-3&3&-8&-7\end{array}\right)$.

Then row reduce and back substitute to get your solutions.

Note:  your $z$ is a member of the kernel.   The kernel is $3$-dimensional,  since the rank is $2$.